# Group by school year in postgres

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have a query where I count the number of rows for each year:

```
SELECT 
  count(*) as activation_count
, extract(year from activated_at) as year
FROM "activations" 
WHERE ... 
GROUP BY year
```

But I'd like instead to have years ranging from September to September instead of January to January. Thus grouping by school years instead of calendar years.

Can I modify my query to do that?

And more generally, is it possible to group by a time range and specify an offset to it, eg: `extract(year from activated_at offset interval 2 month) as year` (this is not working, just the idea of what I want)

Answer (score 3):

What you essentially want is to treat all dates after September as "next year", so the following should work:

```
select count(*) as activation_count,
       case 
          when extract(month from activated_at) >= 9 then extract(year from activated_at) + 1
          else extract(year from activated_at)
       end as school_year
from activations
group by school_year;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that someone whose `activated_at` is '2016-09-01' should be counted as `year = 2017`, you could add 4 months to `activated_at` when in the `extract` (translating (in the mathematical sense of the word) September to January).

```
SELECT * FROM activations ;
┌────────────────────────┐
│      activated_at      │
├────────────────────────┤
│ 2016-08-01 00:00:00+02 │
│ 2016-09-01 00:00:00+02 │
│ 2016-10-01 00:00:00+02 │
│ 2017-02-02 00:00:00+01 │
└────────────────────────┘
(4 rows)


SELECT COUNT(*),
       EXTRACT(year FROM (activated_at + '4 months'::interval)) AS year 
FROM activations
GROUP BY year;
┌───────┬──────┐
│ count │ year │
├───────┼──────┤
│     3 │ 2017 │
│     1 │ 2016 │
└───────┴──────┘
(2 rows)
```

If it should be counted as `year = 2016` you could remove 8 months instead.